# Imagem componente react não carrega (mui material)

Tags: javascript, html, css, react

estou com o seguinte componente como navbar em uma aplicação frontend com react

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, alpha } from '@mui/material/styles';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import InputBase from '@mui/material/InputBase';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';

const Search = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  position: 'relative',
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
  },
  marginLeft: 0,
  width: '100%',
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 'auto',
  },
}));

const SearchIconWrapper = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
  height: '100%',
  position: 'absolute',
  pointerEvents: 'none',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
}));

const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: 'inherit',
  '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)})`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: '12ch',
      '&:focus': {
        width: '20ch',
      },
    },
  },
}));

export default function Navbar({pokemonFilter}) {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, marginBottom:"3em"}}>
      <AppBar position="static" sx={{backgroundColor:"#C22E29"}}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" width="100%">
            <Box component="img" src="/assets/pokelogo.png" alt="logo pokemon" height="3em"/>
            <Search onChange={(e) => pokemonFilter(e.target.value)}>
              <SearchIconWrapper>
                <SearchIcon />
              </SearchIconWrapper>
              <StyledInputBase
                placeholder="Buscar..."
                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
              />
            </Search>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

a imagem na box `<Box component="img" src="/assets/pokelogo.png" alt="logo pokemon" height="3em"/>` não está carregando, alguem saberia dizer o que posso fazer?

Answer (score -1):

```
<Box component="img" src="/assets/pokelogo.png" alt="logo pokemon" height="3em"/>
```

Você está invocando o arquivo diretamente em src, o correto é importar a imagem.

Uma descrição detalhada pode ser obtida em [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files).

> Com o webpack, o uso de recursos estáticos como imagens e fontes funciona de maneira semelhante ao CSS. 
> Você pode criar importum arquivo diretamente em um módulo JavaScript . Isso diz ao webpack para incluir esse arquivo no pacote. Ao contrário das importações de CSS, a importação de um arquivo fornece um valor de string. Esse valor é o caminho final que você pode referenciar em seu código, por exemplo, como o srcatributo de uma imagem ou hrefde um link para um PDF.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, alpha } from '@mui/material/styles';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import InputBase from '@mui/material/InputBase';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import Pokelogo from './assets/pokelogo.png'

const Search = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  position: 'relative',
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
  },
  marginLeft: 0,
  width: '100%',
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 'auto',
  },
}));

const SearchIconWrapper = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
  height: '100%',
  position: 'absolute',
  pointerEvents: 'none',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
}));

const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: 'inherit',
  '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)})`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: '12ch',
      '&:focus': {
        width: '20ch',
      },
    },
  },
}));

export default function Navbar({pokemonFilter}) {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, marginBottom:"3em"}}>
      <AppBar position="static" sx={{backgroundColor:"#C22E29"}}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" width="100%">
            <Box component="img" src={Pokelogo} alt="logo pokemon" height="3em"/>
            <Search onChange={(e) => pokemonFilter(e.target.value)}>
              <SearchIconWrapper>
                {/* <SearchIcon /> */}
              </SearchIconWrapper>
              <StyledInputBase
                placeholder="Buscar..."
                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
              />
            </Search>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}
```